# List of/labels for invalidated patents (for the patent office)

Tags: feature-request, search, up-votes

If a patent is successfully invalidated here, it seems to me like we'd need an easy way to call attention to it for our friends at the patent office.  Upvotes are good, but they're far from definitive, or sufficiently organized.

I would suggest new labels that we can apply to answers.  Depending on how many are ultimately adopted, they may be named "**Possibly Invalidated**", "**Likely Invalidated**", "**Definitely Invalidated**", with more and more stringent upvote requirements for each.  The labels would then be searchable.  If other answers in the question provide additional evidence, the label might be expanded to "**[...] Invalidated with Support**".

Finally, I would suggest that such labels would generally be applied by high rep users, after examining posts exceeding the required threshold of upvotes, but that posts that manage to hit a certain higher threshold on their own would also be automatically labelled.

Answer (score 1):

The decision to invalidate a patent is not ours to make, it is up to the patent examiner. No one here has any authority to invalidate a patent (at least not in their capacity as a Stack Exchange user).

Patent examiners working on a particular patent can look up any thread on this patent and make up their own mind.

If you wish to bring the attention of a patent examiner to a particular thread on this site, submit what has been found in that thread as prior art; see the [FAQ](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq#found-prior-art). You can (should) include the URL to the thread in the description of relevance.